# Symfony2 - slow initialization time when adding a bundle

Tags: php, performance, symfony, filesystems, vagrant

I noticed a big slow performance issue after installing the NelmioApiDocBundle (before: ~250ms, after: ~1800ms), the initialization time has increased significantly.

I disabled xDebug, I'm on a up-to-date Vagrant machine (debian) with NFS on PHP 5.6 with OPCache enabled and I'm on OS X host machine. I tried to move the logs/cache folders into `/dev/shm`, but without any change.

I also noticed that when I switch off the debug mode, the slow issue disappears. So I change the `isFresh` method of the `FileResource` class [(see code)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Resource/FileResource.php#L63) to return always true without checking the `filemtime` and the performance issue is partially gone (~450 ms).

So, why `filemtime` takes so long ?

Comment: I guess you only see this problem in `dev` environment?

Comment: Yes, but not because it's the `dev` environment but because the `debug` mode is enabled.